# how to make spark numbering column by keyword count

Tags: apache-spark, filter

I have dataframe with time-keyword base.

[image]

I want to numbering by keyword in below conditions.

- Condition 1. Divide into time intervals, such as 10 minute intervals (changeable).
- Condition 2. Numbering for each keyword within the interval(10min).
- make numbering column used by .withColumn()

How to make it??

[image]

here is my sample code.

```
class DataSetTest {
String date;
String keyword;

public DataSetTest(String date, String keyword) {
    this.date = date;
    this.keyword = keyword;
}}


DataSetTest ro1 = new DataSetTest("2020.11.26 11:30:00", "apple");
DataSetTest ro2 = new DataSetTest("2020.11.26 11:31:00", "apple");
DataSetTest ro3 = new DataSetTest("2020.11.26 11:32:00", "apple");
DataSetTest ro4 = new DataSetTest("2020.11.26 11:34:00", "banana");
DataSetTest ro5 = new DataSetTest("2020.11.26 11:35:00", "car");
DataSetTest ro6 = new DataSetTest("2020.11.26 11:37:00", "car");
DataSetTest ro7 = new DataSetTest("2020.11.26 11:39:00", "apple");
DataSetTest ro8 = new DataSetTest("2020.11.26 11:40:00", "banana");
DataSetTest ro9 = new DataSetTest("2020.11.26 11:42:00", "car");
DataSetTest ro10 = new DataSetTest("2020.11.26 11:43:00", "banana");
DataSetTest ro11= new DataSetTest("2020.11.26 11:45:00", "apple");
DataSetTest ro12 = new DataSetTest("2020.11.26 11:46:00", "apple");
DataSetTest ro13 = new DataSetTest("2020.11.26 11:50:00", "apple");
DataSetTest ro14= new DataSetTest("2020.11.26 11:51:00", "banana");
DataSetTest ro15= new DataSetTest("2020.11.26 11:52:00", "car");
DataSetTest ro16= new DataSetTest("2020.11.26 11:54:00", "car");
DataSetTest ro17= new DataSetTest("2020.11.26 11:58:00", "banana");
Dataset<Row> df = session.getSqlContext().createDataFrame(Arrays.asList(ro1, ro2, ro3, ro4, ro5, ro6, ro7, ro8, ro9, ro10, ro11, ro12, ro13, ro14, ro15, ro16, ro17), DataSetTest.class);

WindowSpec windowSpec = Window.orderBy("keyword");
dataset.withColumn("index", row_number().over(windowSpec));
```

Comment: can you post sample data instead of screenshot ?

Comment: Post the code u tried to solve the problem?

Comment: sorry. I just added the sample code.

Answer (score 1):

For base intervals you can use *date_trunc* function:

```
SELECT time_truncated, time, keyword, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY time_truncated, keyword ORDER BY time) AS RN
FROM
(
  SELECT *, date_trunc('HOUR', time) AS time_truncated
  FROM table
)t
```

For intervals like '10 minutes' you need a custom date truncation formula:

```
date_trunc('minute', from_unixtime(to_unix_timestamp(time) - minute(time) % 10 * 60)) as time_truncated
```